# Detect session state and automatically redirect to login page in Blazor

Tags: .net, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

In server side blazor application (using ASP.NET core identity) how can we automatically redirect to login page after session timeout. Below is my code in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthenticationCore();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "CookieName";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
            options.SlidingExpiration = false;
            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
        });
        services.AddAuthorizationCore();

        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
    }
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions()
        {
            MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax
        });

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

Also I created RedirectToLogin razor component and added it under App.Razor as like below.

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" >
            <NotAuthorized>
            <RedirectToLogin></RedirectToLogin>
        </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

With these codes after session timeout, webpage is not automatically redirect to login page. And its redirect to login page only if i refresh the page

Comment: For your SPA to detect the session has timed out you need something checking the state of your cookie.  Something like a Scoped Service that captures the initial timeout and raises an event when it occurs.  And an event handler in `App` to  re-render the page when the event handler is triggered.

Comment: Is there any session expire events which i can subscribe?

Comment: Pretty sure No.  You need to create your own as I've described above.

Comment: You have to create a timer to check the session.